# Increase Ram Provided to docker container

Tags: linux, docker, sqlserver

I'm trying to run the [docker mssql](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker) container on a Linux host.

In the tutorial it is described how you should increase the RAM size allocated to the container and how you do that on Windows and Mac using their respective GUIs. How do you do that on Linux where there is no GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you go about doing that in the GUI but using the docker cli you can pass parameters to the `run` command as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources):

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword -d --memory 500m mysql
```

You can specify options to this such as 100m, 1g, etc..

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Sadly the lacking ram doesn't seem to be the issue.